# Is it true that DIV elements cannot be clicked with selenium Web Driver?

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Is it true that DIV elements cannot be clicked with selenium Web Driver?

For Instance, I'm unable to click on delete button in Gmail

[image: Am unblae to thid delete button]

Am trying to locate the elemnt using XPATH = //div[@aria-label='Delete']

[image: Below is the HTML code:]

here, class names and id's are dynamic which changes for every session. Imean, for every Login and Logout. I want my script to be Robust to run at any time.

Comment: do you get any exceptions? `//div[@aria-label='Delete']` seem to work fine

Comment: Yes i get this:

Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 
`By.xpath: //div[@aria-label='Delete']'doesn't exist on the page.`  

FYI, am using page object model, where i locate the elements using @FindBy annotation and use the element inthe script with its name.

And i also get TimeOutException sometimes

Answer (score 1):

You can by class name or ID, e.g. with class:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("class")).click();
```

Or by element name:

```
driver.findElement(By.ByTagName("div")).click();
```

Or find the parent or child `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different attribute ? 
For e.g. you can use

```
//div[@data-tooltip='Delete']
```

or

```
//div[@data-tooltip='Delete']/div/div
```

Answer (score 0):

It may derive because of gmail has async structure. You may wait to finish request after page load and after select action. If you can share code flow we can examine together.